# Sort a Query on a Relations Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My application has tables with sortable columns.  Columns can be sorted on attributes of the present model or even related models.  However, in some cases, a model has multiple associations with a another model.

In this example, Sections have multiple relations that must be loaded along side it.
relation1 and relation2 are actually records from the same database table.  If i run the query and try to sort on teacher, it will actually sort on students because they come from the same table and that's what is used for sorting.

```
Section.includes(:teacher, :students)
       .order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
```

which generates this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `sections`.id
FROM `sections` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `sections_students` ON `sections_students`.`section_id` = `sections`.`id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `sections_students`.`user_id` 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` `teachers_sections` ON `teachers_sections`.`id` = `sections`.`teacher_id`
ORDER BY users.first_name asc LIMIT 30 OFFSET 0
```

How can I sort on a specific relation?  Is there a way to use aliases to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Notice the alias for teachers:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` `teachers_sections`
```

You should be able to use that alias:

```
order("teachers.#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
```